# Apache Ignite, Scan Query without filter and Iterator over cache, both returns empty result set. The number of entries in the cache is non-zero

Tags: ignite

Apache Ignite Version: 2.8.0

While starting the first ignite cache node, below code snippets, give expected output. When the second ignite cache joins the cluster, the entries object in the first code snippet is empty while in the second snippet iter.hasNext() gives false.

1. The ignite cluster is started with ShareNothing persistance.
2. Cache mode is set to CacheMode.REPLICATED.
3. Both the nodes are in server mode.
4. call to size() in both instances give a non-zero value.
5. call to localSize() gives non-zero value in the first instance, but 0 in second instance.

   ```
    Map results = new HashMap();
    QueryCursor<Cache.Entry> entries = binaryCache.query(new ScanQuery(null));
    logger.log(Level.DEBUG, "CacheSize from entrySet: [%s]", binaryCache.size()); // Outputs non zero number. 
    try {
      for (Cache.Entry e : entries) {
        results.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error deserializing ignite entry", e);
    }
    return results.entrySet();
   ```

OR

```
    Map results = new HashMap();
    Iterator<Cache.Entry<Object, BinaryObject>> iter = binaryCache.iterator();
    logger.log(Level.DEBUG, "CacheSize from entrySet: [%s]", binaryCache.size()); // Outputs non zero number. 
    try {
      while(iter.hasNext()) {
        Cache.Entry e = iter.next();
        results.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error deserializing ignite entry", e);
    }
    
    return results.entrySet();
```

As null is passed to ScanQuery, ideally, all the entries from the cache should be fetched.

Comment: Your snippets look ok and should be fine. Is it possible to get a full reproducer? I.e. how do you obtain your cache instances and invoke the iterators?

Comment: @AlexandrShapkin, 
For each cache instance --> ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfig).withKeepBinary();
and all the nodes are in server mode.

Comment: @AlexandrShapkin, I have added some more observations. Please have a look at it if its useful.

Comment: Are you sure that the entries are not removed somehow and you are not iterating over the same iterator? Also, it's not clear, what is your goal? If you just want to get the stored values then the cache object itself is iterable and it's better to use your second example

Comment: Please, check the answer with a code example and try to run it

Comment: @AlexandrShapkin #1 yes the entries are not removed. That's why the size of cache is non-zero.  #2 Not iterating on the same iterator. #3 Goal: When I start the second node, I should get the existing entries from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

IgniteCache is iterable, as you noticed in the second example.
If you need to get the stored values, the simplest code would be like:

```
        IgniteCache<Object, BinaryObject> myCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(ccfg).withKeepBinary();
        for(Cache.Entry<Object, BinaryObject> entry: myCache){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println("trying again");

        for(Cache.Entry<Object, BinaryObject> entry: myCache){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If cache has cache store, it may desync since cache store loads are not propagated across cluster. This is how cache store works on replicated caches.